# How to handle "./", "~/" and related arguments in a CLI application

Tags: rust, command-line-interface

I am creating a CLI application in Rust and would like to allow the user to run `app ~/Desktop` for example, in order to run the app in the user's Desktop directory. So, the question is if there is any shortcut to implementing arguments like this or would I have to implement my own system for parsing them, like a `.` argument setting the directory to Rust's `current_dir()` function, etc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The shell will expand `~`. Your application does not need to handle it.

`.` and `..` are handled by the operating system. You also don't need to do anything special for them.